# pretty printing of complex numbers

Tags: python, formatting, complex-numbers

I have a list of complex numbers created as the output of a 1d discrete Fourier transform.  Id like to be able to display them in a neat column with the real and imaginary parts rounded off to 4 decimal places each; something like:

```
21.0000 +  0.0000j
-3.0000 +  5.1962j
-3.0000 +  1.7321j
-3.0000 +  0.0000j
-3.0000 -  1.7321j
-3.0000 -  5.1962j
```

and of course nicely lined up along the decimal points.  Is there an easy way to do this - some way of formatting complex numbers?

Comment: Are they python complex numbers or `numpy`?

Comment: When you say _rounded_, do you really mean rounded or just truncated? In other words, do you just want to display them upto 4 decimals resolution, or round them up or down?

Comment: I don't hugely care at the moment if they're rounded or truncated; it's only for display purposes and I just want a nice listing.

Answer (score 3):

Use the new [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) function.

```
>>> a = -3 + 5.3j
>>> a
(-3+5.3j)
>>> "{num.real:+0.04f} {num.imag:+0.04f}j".format(num=a)
'-3.0000 +5.3000j'
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was looking at the format function, but I had not got far enough in my reading to be able to translate from c-style printf formatting codes.  This is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
print '%0.4f + %0.4fi' % (a.real, a.imag)
```

Comment: After posting I discovered this as an answer to a different question.  It works well, but it would be nice if, as in my example above, there would be a space between the sign of the imaginary part and its value.

Comment: @Alasdair You can have tab as a separator.

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is something like '2.0000 + 3.0000i", whereas the format commands give me "2.0000 +3.0000i"; that is, I'd like a space to the right of the "+" symbol.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
>>> a = -3 - 5.3j
>>> "{num.real:+0.04f} {num.imag:=+8.04f}j".format(num=a)
'-3.0000 - 5.3000j'
```